# AWS GreenGrass version 2 JavaScript console log not available

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, console.log, aws-iot-greengrass

I'm trying to get console.log() calls from JavaScript to show in a log file in AWS GreenGrass version 2. Version 1 has a "Local logs configuration" option area, under "Groups" -> "Settings", but I haven't been able to find any comparable settings for version 2. I see various log files in /greengrass/v2/logs, but none of them show my console.log() calls.

Thanks for any help on this...

Comment: I have the aws.greengrass.LogManager component deployed, as well.

Answer (score 0):

My GreenGrass lambda was not getting called, I added console.log() call that always happens, and I uninstalled and reinstalled Greengrass, and now I see log messages.

Uninstall: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/v2/developerguide/uninstall-greengrass-core-v2.html
Install: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/v2/developerguide/install-greengrass-core-v2.html